# How to get the value of a wildcard in a string Java?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, string, parsing

This code works in javascript, is it possible to do something similar in java? (get the value of a wildcard in a string)

```
    var a = "HI MY NAME IS BOB"

    var b = /HI MY NAME IS (.*)/

    alert("HI " + b.exec(a)[1])
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all? Put some effort to elaborate.

Comment: You've tagged your question `regex`. Do you know what regular expressions are?

Comment: use [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to try the regex

Comment: Why did you remove the regex tag from your question? A paraphrase of your question is "How do I use regex in Java?"

Comment: @nnnnnn, Because I was unsure if there would be a non-regex answer (somehow), but seeing as the answer is regex based, I will put the tag back.

Comment: You might want to use a substring method. For example: var a = "HI MY NAME IS BOB"; System.out.printf("Substring from index 14 is\%s\n",a.substring(14)); This would print from the 14th index to end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to find **captured group #1**:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)Hi MY NAME IS (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hi MY NAME IS BOB");
if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println( "Group #1: " + m.group(1) ); // BOB
}
```

- `(?i)` is for ignore case match
- `m.group(1)` will give value of first captured group from your regex i.e. `(.*)`

Comment: Also check, that the first string is `HI`, when your regex is `HY`, it seems a typo in the Question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [java.util.regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package.

The syntax of regular expressions is a whole different answer, but I'll assume you're somewhat familiar with it here.

To use a regex in Java, you'll need to create two objects, a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`.

Quoting the documentation, a `Pattern` object is "A compiled representation of a regular expression", and a `Matcher` object is "An engine that performs match operations on a character sequence by interpreting a `Pattern`."

In other words, you use a `Pattern` to define your regex, and a `Matcher` to apply it.

So let's take this line-by-line:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
String a = "MY NAME is BOB";
```

Obviously, you need to import the package and define the string you're going to apply the regex to.

```
Pattern wildcard = Pattern.compile("HI MY NAME IS (.*)");
```

`Pattern.compile` takes a `String` representing a regex and returns a `Pattern`.

```
Matcher match = wildcard.matcher(a);
```

`Pattern` objects have an instance method, `matcher`, that takes the string you want to apply the `Pattern` to, and returns a `Matcher`.

```
System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

Calling `match.group(n)` returns the string matching the n<sup>th</sup> group of parentheses (to be more precise, the n<sup>th</sup> *capturing group*) in your regex. `match.group(0)`, which is equivalent to `match.group()`, returns the string representing your entire match. In this case, we're using `match.group(1)` because we want to match the only set of parentheses in our regex - the `(.*)` at the end.

Putting it all together, we get:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
String a = "MY NAME is BOB";
Pattern wildcard = Pattern.compile("HI MY NAME IS (.*)");
Matcher match = wildcard.matcher(a);
System.out.println(match.group(1));
```

Comment: This is a clear and good answer, but the same thing was already provided by anubhava.

Answer (score 0):

The class you need is `Pattern`. It is similar to `regex` in its functions, but the mechanics are different. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not entirely what you asked for but I want to try to be little helpful. You can print out "BOB" using the substring(). Here is what worked for me: String a = new String("Hi my name is Bob");
System.out.printf("This print as Bob\n%s",a.substring(14)); The substring starts at index 14 and prints to the end of the string.

Comment: I thought of that, but already it is to simple for what I need